# Callout from an LWC page

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, integration, callout, rest

Hi Have a below code in apex

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
string accessToken;
request.setEndpoint(URL);
request.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) 
    JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    accessToken = (string)results.get('access_token');
}
```

Now whatever the response body received from this, needs to be iterated on the LWC page so I made the above method as auraEnabled and calling it on JS and it is working perfactly fine but instead, I am trying to skip the apex part and wants to call out on LWC page itself so to do the same I wrote below JS code.

JS code:

```
 fetch(endPoint, {
    method: "POST"
})
.then((response) => response.json())
/* response.json() gives us back a promise
we need to process the promise in .then()*/
.then((repos) => {
    console.log(repos);

});
```

and also I have added the endpoint under CSP trusted sites and remote site settings of course.

[image]

[image]

and checked all the boxes

I am getting the below error

> Access to fetch at 'myendpointhere' from origin
> 'https://mydomain.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you added the endpoints to CORS? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_endpoints_cors.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I have added but it is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

try using `mode: "no-cors"`.

```js
const accessToken = 'super-secret-access-token-here'

fetch(endPoint, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  }
})
```

also don't forget to pass in the Authorization token you were using in Apex (I assume you still need it).

Comment: Actually, I am getting the error when making a first post call to get the access token

Comment: sorry for posting the get request, I have updated my question with the post request I am making to get the access token

Comment: should work the same whether its a `GET` or `POST` request, the main point there is adding `mode: "no-cors"` which should bypass the CORS issues.